# R for loop in matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have two 365x1 matrix s1 and s2, mean and standard deviation vector.
I want to simulate normal distribution for a new 365x1 matrix. the code I used is

```
sim<-matrix(rep(NA,365),nrow=365,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:365){y<-rnorm(1,s1[i,],s2[i,])
 sim[i,]<-y[i]}
```

However it only generates first value. How should I fix my codes?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, since you are relatively new here you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made much more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote a useful answer. You are under absolutely no obligation to do either, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop. rnorm is vectorised so just do this...

```
s1 <- sample(10,365,repl=TRUE)
s2 <- sample(3,365,repl=TRUE)
rnorm( 365 , s1 , s2 )
#[1]  5.83648500  1.64208807  0.02800676 -1.76443571  5.15361880  2.88269571
.
.
.
```

This will draw 365 random normal deviates using each of the values in the mean and standard deviation vectors `s1` and `s2` in turn.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only getting one value is because in `{y<-rnorm(...`, you're assigning to a scalar variable `y`. In the next line, you try to get the value of `y[i]`, which won't exist for `i` greater than 1.

HOWEVER, you don't need a loop at all. The `rnorm` function is vectorised, meaning it accepts vectors as arguments for the mean and standard deviation. So you can fill your `sim` vector with

```
sim <- rnorm(365, s1, s2)
```

Comment: does that mean if I make y a matrix, my codes should work? how can I do that in loop?